# How to provide sudo command/password once after connecting to the server using python

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

Once after connecting to the unix server with my id credentials, I am trying to login as sudo user by providing sudo command and password. I tried different ways, but I am not successful. Below is my code

```
import paramiko
import time

#define SSH
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(policy=paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)

#Connect to ther server
ssh.connect('server',22,username='username',password='password')



transport = ssh.get_transport()

#create a channel
chan = transport.open_session()

#interactive shell
chan.get_pty()
chan.invoke_shell()
print(chan.recv(2000))

#execute command
chan.exec_command('sudo S su - test server')
chan.send('password')
chan.send('\n')
chan.exec_command('whoami')
print(chan.recv(2000))
chan.close()
```

is there any other way to provide the sudo commanfd and password

Answer (score 0):

I've always used paramiko shell to do such things.  It would basically mean treating it like 'expect' where it checks for a prompt based on some regex pattern to see the completion of a command.  Based on the response from the command output or the prompt, you can send the subsequent command.

Here's a more complete overview:
https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect